# "Error using ==> plot Vectors must be the same lengths." for vectors of same length

Tags: matlab, plot

I have a problem with this error. I have two matrices, days1 and days2, with size:

```
[size(days1) size(days2)]

ans =

      14749           2       14749           2
```

So they have the same length and depth.

However, when I try to plot the two graphs together, I get the following error:

```
plot(days1(1,:),days1(:,2),'b',days2(1,:),days2(:,2),'r')
??? Error using ==> plot
Vectors must be the same lengths.
```

What's the reason?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vectors you are plotting are not the same length:

```
>> size(days1(1,:))
ans =

   1   2

>> size(days1(:,2))
ans =

   14749       1
```

Comment: You are right!! I have to do `plot(days1(:,1),days1(:,2),'b',days2(:,1),days2(:,2),'r')`
Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

That is because:

```
days1(1,:)    days1(:,2)
^ [1 x 2]     ^ [14749 x 1]
```

which are obviously NOT the same length :)